# VMware Workstation 9: How to upload and download VM from and to a remote server

Tags: vmware-workstation, vsphere

I am evaluating VMware workstation 9. I am connected to our VMware Vsphere 5 server and I can open VMs and so on.

I would like to donwload a VM from VSphere to my local Workstation, however when I right click the VM and choose Manage, the option for upload and download is grey and not clickable.

How do I make them accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible to download VMs that are turned off.

1. Right click the VM and choose open
2. Right click the VM again and choose Manage.
3. Now the download option is available.